# Android EditText misbehaving on certain devices, especially HTC

Tags: android, textview

I have a several EditTexts in a very dense/compact TextView-full application that are 3 characters wide. It displays normally on most devices and on the emulator. However on the HTC Evo 3D, HTC myTouch 4G, and a Viewsonic gTablet the EditText is twice as wide as it should be.

Stripping away as much as possible while still replicating the behaviour:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editTextFoo"
    android:hint="123"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:minEms="3"
    android:maxEms="3"/>
```

I can constrain it by specifying in pixels, dp, or sp instead of wrap_content, but it's pretty unsatisfying with all the layouts for different screens sizes and densities.

Are EditTexts implemented to have a minimum width on some devices?

EDIT: I am experiencing this for several different layout types.

Comment: You probably want to consider using a different layout structure, such as `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question:

A bit counterintuitive, but I grabbed some code from a game I had previously made. Paint's measureText method worked well. If you're using a monospace font, any n-letter string will do.

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTextSize(editTextFoo.getTextSize());
int w = (int) p.measureText("MMM");
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(w+40,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
editTextFoo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```